# Just the First Result of Text Find

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

I have the following code:

```
indexOfSearchText = TextBox1.Find(item, start, TextBox1.TextLength, RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord)

If indexOfSearchText <> -1 Then
  startindex = indexOfSearchText
End If
```

but i want just the first result, if I have an example text:

> this is an example. lala and this is another example

then it searches twice "is", I just want the first "is".

Answer (score 1):

Your `start` parameter is obviously higher than the value 5, which would be the value of the first "is" word it would find.

Somewhere in the code you aren't showing is how you are setting and passing the parameter for that `start` variable.